# Como colocar quebra de linha em um textarea?

Tags: php

Quando eu for alterar ou incluir algum dado de uma `textearea` eu queria que salvasse as quebras de linhas. E também, quando for mostrar numa `textarea` antes os dados que já existem eu queria que mostrasse com as quebras de linhas.

Depois eu junto os dois `textarea` e salvo no banco. Já olhei os códigos de quebrar linha e tentei aqui e não deu certo, alguém pode me ajudar?

```html
Observações:</p>
<p>
    <textarea name="obs" cols="150" rows="10" style="resize:none" readonly ><?php echo $obs; ?></textarea> <!-- Aqui somente mostra os dados do banco e queria com as quebras de linhas. -->
</p>

<br>
Para adicionar dados usar o campo abaixo.
<textarea name="obs1" rows="10" cols="150" style="resize:none" ></textarea> <!-- Aqui a pessoa digita o que irá adicionar com o texto acima e queria com quebra de linha. -->
```

Comment: Tentou usar o `nl2br($obs)` ?

Comment: eu coloquei no primeiro textearea <?php echo nl2br($obs); ?> e nao ta quebrando as linhas. no primeiro tem que mostrar as linhas em cada linha separado e no segundo eu digito o texto e se eu der enter quero que salve com as quebras. porem como eu to junto os dois text area tem que ter uma quebra de linha entre eles

Comment: Mas você está salvando o texto no banco usando o `nl2br` ?

Comment: nao pq ja tentei por e nao aceita da erro.

Comment: Dá erro ? Mas não deveria... assim, tem que salvar com `nl2br` e puxar com `nl2br`.

Comment: fiz aki e ate deu. porem ele fica mostrando o <br> dentro do text area é assim mesmo? texte5<br /><br /><br /><br />
texte6texte7, o texte 6 e 7 ta grudado pq no seguno texte area eu junto com o primeiro e eu queria q a linha ficasse quebrada nisso tbm.

Comment: Não, não é assim. Faz assim: `$quebras = array("<br />","<br>","<br/>");  
    $text = str_ireplace($quebras, "\r\n", $obs);`. Depois tira o `nl2br` e faz `echo $obs` no **textarea** pra ver.

Comment: o <br> continua aparecendo dentro do text area

Comment: Como você fez ? Eu errei no final. É `echo $text`.

Comment: eu tinha colocado do jeito q vc falo ai mudei pro $text e deu certo. so a junção do textarea1 e do 2 que ta grudado. tipo eu junto o $obs com $obs1 e regravo no banco pq eu eu quero adicionar informação eu mostro o q ja tem e no campo de baixo escreve o que precisa adicionar e dai junto os dois no final... eu tava fazendo de outro jeito mas como eu sei que vao fazer errado to desmembrando.

Comment: estou fazendo teste aki e conforme eu vou editando as informações ele ta pondo quebra de linha a mais do que deveria. tipo em vez de pular uma conforme eu vou adicionando informação ele ta pondo mais de uma quebra de linha nos dados anrteriores

Comment: Edita sua pergunta e coloca seu código atual.

Comment: mexi aki e consegui resolver valeu!!

Comment: tem como me dar mais uma ajuda? preciso mostrar esse campo de $obs q eu peguei na textarea mas sem ser dentro dela e com as quebras de linhas

Comment: É só tirar o `textarea` não e usar a variável do mesmo jeito.

Comment: eu tirei o textarea e ta mostrando tudo em uma linha e nao ta quebrando.

Comment: consegui coloquei o <?php echo nl2br($text); ?> e foi, hj ta dificio de pensar....

Answer (score 5):

você pode concatenar a sua string com `&#10;`

```
<textarea cols='60' rows='8'>Primeira Linha.&#10;Segunda Linha</textarea>
```

Answer (score 4):

Salve no banco de dados com as quebras de linhas do `<textarea>`:

```
str_replace("\n",'<br />', addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['valor']
// OPCIONAL: addslashes é para conversão do caracter ' e não dá conlflito no BD
// OPCIONAL: htmlspecialchars é para não permitir caracteres especiais
```

Para pegar o valor do `<textarea>` no banco de dados faça assim:

```
str_replace('<br />', "\n", $valor);
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode colocar usando:

```
Echo nl2br($row['campo']);
```

Comment: com row nao funciona nao aceita