# Erro com quebra de linha no <textarea>

Tags: php, html

Bom tenho um campo no banco de dados Mysql do tipo marchar 255.

Montei um textarea assim:

```
<textarea name="obs" maxlength="255"></textarea>
```

Se eu colocar 255 caracter dentro dele, eu consigo salvar sem problemas. Porém se eu apagar um caracter e pular uma linha eu não consigo salvar.
Alguém sabe como resolver isso? remover as quebras de linhas?

Estou capturando ele assim:

```
$obs = addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'obs', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));
```

--------- Editei ------

Notei que para cada quebra de linha, ela salva esse valor no bd `&#13;&#10;`

Comment: Após apagar um caractere e pular uma linha e tentar salvar o que ocorre? Se um erro ocorrer, copie e cole aqui o conteúdo do erro para melhor compreensão da questão, por favor.

Comment: o erro é esse Data too long for column 'obs' at row 1

Comment: Faça uma verificação na variável que armazena o conteúdo do `textarea` para o tamanho do conteúdo antes de tentar salvar no banco. Antes disso você pode até tentar remover quebras de linha com `$textarea = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/", "", $textarea)` ou cortar o conteúdo para verificar o que fica de fora com `$textarea = substr ($textarea , 0, 255)`

Comment: bom se eu usar o `substr` funciona, ele corta 3 letras para cada quebra de linha, o problema e que não fica legal. E sua forma de remover as quebras com preg_replace não deu certo

Comment: com 3 replaces vc resolve seu problema, veja na minha resposta;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu usei o seguinte código em HTML+PHP para testar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['textarea'])) {
      $raw_textarea = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'textarea');
      $raw_textarea_length = strlen($raw_textarea);
      $textarea = preg_replace("/([\n\r]+|[\s]{2,})/", "", nl2br($raw_textarea));
      $textarea_length = strlen($textarea);
    } else {
      $raw_textarea = "";
      $raw_textarea_length = 0;
      $textarea = "";
      $textarea_length = 0;
    }
    ?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
      <input type="number" value="<?=$raw_textarea_length?>"> <br>
      <input type="number" value="<?=$textarea_length?>"> <br>
      <input type="text" value="<?=$textarea?>"> <br>
      <textarea name="textarea" rows="8" cols="80" maxlength="128">
        Alguma coisa acontece no meu coração
        Só quando eu cruzo a Ipiranga
        Com a avenida São João
  alsjkdna</textarea> <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

E pude notar que:

- Apesar do campo ser limitado a 128 caracteres, ele estava contendo 132 caracteres e ainda pude escrever mais 4 mesmo os mesmos sendo removidos ao clicar em no Submit, ou seja, não dá pra confiar completamente no atributo `maxlength`
- Usando a função `nl2br` aumenta consideravelmente o comprimento da string por adicionar `<br />`, 6 caracteres antes de cada `\n` ou `\r\n` que são apenas 2 ou 4 caracteres respectivamente
- Remover os espaços extras e substituir quebras de linha reduz consideravelmente o tamanho da string com `preg_replace("/([\n\r]+|[\s]{2,})/", "", nl2br($raw_textarea));`

Sugiro que você aumente o tamanho no campo no MySQL ou reduza na página e que, caso precise de exatidão, controle o tamanho da string dentro da `textarea` com JavaScript para limitar a quantidade de informação a ser permitida antes do envio.

**------------------ EDIT ------------------**

Com a alteração na sua pergunta que informa sobre esses caracteres especiais ao salvar no banco, use `preg_replace("/([\n\r]+|[\s]{2,})/", "", nl2br($raw_textarea));` para que o banco não precise escapar os caracteres especiais de quebra de linha e seu problema deve ser resolvido.

Answer (score 1):

### **Como que eu resolvo o problema de forma imediata?**

*Não é uma gambiarra, e sim uma opção, afinal gambiarra é coisa bem pior que isso. Você tem a opção de salvar no banco de dados com as quebras de linha, inclusive utilizei muito essa técnica e dá certo, dependendo da tua necessidade, se tu quer complicar muito o processo, ou fazer algo simplificado e funcional.
Com o STR_REPLACE buscando substituir cada quebra de linha pela parte que você deseja salva:*

### Para fins de estudo, entendendo a função utilizada

[Entendendo a função str_replace utilizada](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp)

> A função str_replace () substitui alguns caracteres por outros
>   caracteres em uma string.
>
> Esta função funciona pelas seguintes regras:
>
> 1. Se a seqüência de caracteres a ser pesquisada for uma matriz, ela
>      retornará uma matriz
> 2. Se a seqüência a ser pesquisada for uma matriz, localizar e
>      substituir é executado com cada elemento da matriz
> 3. Se ambos encontrar e substituir são matrizes, e substituir tem menos
>      elementos do que encontrar, uma seqüência vazia será usada como
>      substituir
> 4. Se localizar é uma matriz e substituir é uma string, a seqüência de
>      substituição será usada para cada valor de localizar

### Colocando a teoria em prática

[Citação utilizada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/92907/70128)

> Salve no banco de dados com as quebras de linhas do :
>
> ```
> str_replace("\n",'<brSalve no banco de dados com as quebras de linhas do <textarea>:
>
> str_replace("\n",'<br />', addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['valor']
> ```
>
> // OPCIONAL: addslashes é para conversão do caracter ' e não dá
>   conlflito no BD  // OPCIONAL: htmlspecialchars é para não permitir
>   caracteres especiais  //Para pegar o valor do  no banco de
>   dados faça assim:
>
> ```
> str_replace('<br />', "\n", $valor); />', addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['valor']
> ```
>
> // OPCIONAL: addslashes é para conversão do caracter ' e não dá
>   conlflito no BD  // OPCIONAL: htmlspecialchars é para não permitir
>   caracteres especiais  //Para pegar o valor do  no banco de
>   dados faça assim:
>
> ```
> str_replace('<br />', "\n", $valor);
> ```

### Observações:

### O PHP te oferece uma extensa gama de oportunidades de resolver um problema de diferentes maneiras, procure um que se encaixe melhor no seu estilo de programação.

Dúvidas, a disposição.

Answer (score 1):

Os problemas se resumem aos caracteres `&#13;&#10;`

Então não é necessário tanto código para sanar esse pequeno detalhe.

Bastam 3 replaces:

```
$obs = addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'obs', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));
$obs = str_replace("&#13;",' ', $obs );
$obs = str_replace("&#10;",' ', $obs );
$obs = preg_replace(array("/\t/", "/\s{2,}/", "/\n/"), array("", " ", " "), $obs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece porque quando você pula uma linha ele insere um `\n\r`, que são dois caracteres, aí quando você vai pegar ele, tem mais que 255 caracteres.

O `\n` é um caracter que quebra a linha, e o `\r` é um caracter que diz pra ele voltar o cursor pro início da linha

Copie o texto do textarea depois de dar um enter, e cole no Notepad++, ativando a opção de mostrar todos os caracteres, e ele vai mostrar isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sou muito bom em PHP, mas acho que você pode resolver usando a seguinte linha para remover a ocorrência desses caracteres:

`$text = str_replace("\r\n",'', $text);`

Comment: o erro isso mesmo eu acho, mas sua solução não deu certo

Comment: o código não da erro, o erro ocorre no update que tento no mysql.